# Using a Toggle Class within a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function which triggers an event on mouseenter(an overlay) that I subsequently have to unbind.  Within that function, there is an x that I would like to close the overlay and allow the user to be able to retrigger the event.  Right now, it won't work with the unbind(which I need) and even if I take the unbind event out of my code, the css formatting is off.

Here is my function:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).mouseenter(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var docHeight = $(document).height() - ($(document).height() * .1); 
    if(event.pageY > docHeight){
      $("#overlay").show();
      displayOverlay();
      displayModal(itemCount, imageArray, cartTotal);
      $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
    }
    $("#x").click(function(){
      $("#overlay").hide();
    });
  });
});
```

and here is my CSS:

```
function displayOverlay() {
  $("<div id='overlay'></div>").css({
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": "0px",
    "height": "1200px",
    "width": "100%",
    "z-index": 100,
    "background-color": "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
  }).appendTo("body");
}

function displayModal(itemCount, imageArray, cartTotal) {
  var imageHTML = "";
  for (i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++){
    imageHTML += imageArray[i];
  }
  if (imageHTML === ""){
    imageHTML = "You do not have any items in your cart";
  }
  $("<article id='modal'><div id='itemCount'>" + "Total Items: "
    + itemCount + "<div id='images'>" + imageHTML +
    "<div id='cartTotal'>" + "Subtotal $" + cartTotal + "<div id='x'>"
    + "(X)" + "</div></div></div></div></article>").css({
    "width": "461px",
    "height": "263px",
    "line-height": "200px",
    "position": "fixed",
    "top": "50%",
    "left": "50%",
    "margin-top": "-155px",
    "margin-left": "-232px",
    "background-color": "rgb(255,255,255)",
    "border-radius": "5px",
    "text-align": "center",
    "z-index": 101,
    "border": "1px solid rgb(227,227,227)",
    "border-top": "4px solid rgb(217,0,31)"
  }).appendTo("#overlay");
  $("#itemCount").css({
    "position": "relative",
    "bottom": "79px",
    "font-family": "Helvetica",
    "color": "#000",
    "font-size": "20px"
  }).appendTo("#modal");
  $("#images").css({
    "position": "relative",
    "bottom": "87px"
  }).appendTo("#itemCount");
  $("#cartTotal").css({
    "position": "relative",
    "bottom": "182px",
    "color": "gray",
    "font-size": "18px"
  }).appendTo("#images");
  $(".buttons").css({
    "line-height": "10px",
    "position": "relative",
    "bottom":"86px"
  }).appendTo("#cartTotal");
  $("#x").css({
    "position": "relative",
    "top": "9px",
    "font-size": "16px"
  }).appendTo(".buttons");
  $("a").css({
    "color": "white"
  });
}
```

Comment: I should have mentioned above, that I am making a change to a website all through a javascript script.

Comment: What's the purpose of unbinding "mouseenter" and "mouseleave"? You want those events to run only one time?

Comment: There is an opaque background being triggered on mouseenter and without unbinding the mouseenter, the background will change.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $(this), try specifying an actual element (or selector) name.

```
$(document).unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave');
```

Also, may be it's because you're specifying both events in one unbind() function.